# Вывод из DateTimePicker в label C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

Написать программу, содержащую компонент DateTimePicker и метку. При выборе в DateTimePicker даты (дата рождения пользователя) в метке должен появляться следующий текст «Вы родились … дней назад в <день недели>. В этом году ваш день рождения выпадет на <день недели>.».

Низкий вам поклон

Comment: Обычная задача на использовани класса `DateTime`, что именно у вас не получается? Или вы просто хотите, чтобы задачу решили за вас?

Comment: Не понимаю как оформить вывод по требованию преподавателя

Comment: Вам поможет обработчик события [`DateTimePicker.ValueChanged`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.valuechanged?view=netcore-3.0).

Comment: действие по событию ValueChanged  если мне не изменяет память

Comment: Спасибо большое